# Getting my feet wet with asp.net mvc - I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed what to choose

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm a fellow winform/wpf dev. Everything seems to move into the web atm.
Well I've got php and html5/css3 experience, but asp.net seems not that straight forward.

With the upcoming asp.net vNext I'm confused which technology to choose. To get into it,
I've decided to do a simple ass-hat youtube online converter.

On the one side people claim to choose always the best and latest ones, but on the other side
they are not.

Does it even matter? Is vNext that different from what we got today?

I'm sorry to ask such a "simple" question, but in the past no one told me to choose wpf.. you can imagine what happened :)

I'm a huge fan of telerik. Is telerik the to go suite for asp.net?

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET vNext is still in preview. For someone new to ASP.NET I would recommend looking at [Get Started with ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/get-started). For a "standard" website I would recommend [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc), and for a SPA-like application using e.g. AngularJS I would recommend [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend  going with a stable version choose the latest ASP.NET MVC 5 , you can always find simple and informative tutorials on [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/), and yes , telerik is one among the best 3rd part controls, which you can easily integrate with asp.net mvc.

If you are going for more pure web development, you can choose asp.net web api to host service as http and consume them using jquery ajax and several other clients